# Accuracy in addition

Tags: c++, c, addition

I am working on a tool in C to count some incoming/outgoing bits, I want to preserve the bits and not lose them by changing to bytes.

In the end I want to display xxxxx bits downloaded/uploaded. I am putting the maximum on 10GB=85899345920bits which needs roughly 35 bits to be represented. I am using a 32 bit OS.
I tried unsigned long and unsigned int but they overloaded.

Any easy way to get the addition process and preserve accuracy?

Comment: What compiler are you using? All the major compilers support 64-bit arithmetic, even on 32-bit architectures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a bit of a hybrid approach: store the number of *bytes* into one variable and the number of *bits* that are extra into another variable. Similar to how POSIX systems return the time since the epoch in both seconds *and* microseconds:

```
       struct timeval {
           time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
           suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
       };
```

When you get a transfer of `1505` bits, store:

```
bytes += (1505/8); // ==188
bits += (1505%8); // ==1
```

This way you can keep track of bits.

Or you could take all the fun out of it and use a [`long long`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Long-Long.html).

Comment: @Syntax_Error "At least 64 bits". Gotta love C, it's hard to nail things down some times :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MSVC, you can use __int64 or LONGLONG.

It, or equivalents, may be supported in others.

If not, I think you should go with Joe's answer, but when necessary, just store the additional 0 to 7 bits in a separate char or int. Any other additional bits should go into that store, and when it "overflows" (i.e. 8 bits or more), just take 8 away, but add 1 to your bytes count.

EDIT:
long long ?

Comment: I think it will be platform dependant, but on almost everything it will be 64. It may sometimes be 128, but I don't think it will ever be as small as 32. I think it might be a suck-it-and-see job!

Comment: If you're the kind of person who trusts Wikipedia, there's a sections on this page about "Specific C-language data models":
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that there are 8 bits in a byte (it's a safe assumption in many cases!) then you can just store the number of bytes, and multiply that by 8 when you display it. Your software is probably dealing with buffers of at least a byte at a time.

Comment: @Joe,GMan: not really i want up accuracy to bit level. the byte approach was not accuracte

Comment: @GMan: if I have 9 bits and want to represent them as bytes, it would be 1 or 2 bytes ( 8 or 16) I can't know how much exactly

Comment: @Syntax: You're getting raw bits? That's extremely unusual.

Comment: How / where are these bits being sent?

Answer (score 1):

`uint64_t` (from `<stdint.h>`) will give you 64 bits. (For you particular compiler and OS this is the same as `unsigned long long`, but it's better to use a fixed width type such as `uint64_t` for this).